# Unable to get/set contents of tiny mce editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg, rte

I am using Tiny MCE editor version : 3.5.7
I am using multiple instances of text editor on same page with unique IDs and I have wrapped these editors in a div to show and hide these editors. Everything was working fine. Now I want to clear the contents of the editor when user hide it (so that when it is displayed again the previous contents are removed). I tried to do it using **tinyMCE.get('editorId').setContent('')**, it works fine only once.... I mean once I  have used the above function than I am unable to **set** or even **get** the contents of that editor instance. The structure that I have used is as follows:

```
<div id="parentDIV">
  <div id="1_editor">
  </div>
</div>

tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "exact",
        max_char: "2000",
        elements: "1_editor",
        // Setting up ToolBar
        theme: "advanced",
        theme_advanced_layout_manager: "SimpleLayout",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline, strikethrough,     separator,justifyleft, justifycenter,justifyright,  justifyfull, separator,bullist,numlist,separator,fontselect ,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    });
```

To show and hide the editor I doing something like this:

```
$('#parentDIV').hide();
$('#parentDIV').show();
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: check this fiddle out http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Tpcaab

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure why this happens. One option is if an editor gets moved around the dom. For you it might be a better way to shut down your editors explicitly then to just hide them.

To shut down an edtor instance use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,'editor_id');
```

To reinitialize use

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,'editor_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....but I dont think this is a good approach as I have seen the documentation and the above commands are used to destroy and create the editor...which will definitely effect the performance....ref: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers

Comment: yes, performance will suffer. Usually hide and show should work as it does in rajesh kakawat's fiddle.